# Redirecting HTTPS to HTTP in Magento with checkout exception (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect, https

I am using a Magento installation with the one step checkout plugin, meaning I have very few pages that need HTTPS. I want to control HTTPS search indexing and user access by redirecting the whole HTTPS version of the site *except of course* for the secure checkout.

The secure checkout section is `/onestepcheckout/` (and also includes some sub pages of that, i.e. `onestepcheckout/failure`).

This is what I have so far but the HTTPS is not kicking in on the checkout page with this code, the redirect works in all other case (i.e. I send index HTTPS to index HTTP) just the exception that is broken:

```
#Redirect HTTPS to HTTP except checkout 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^onestepcheckout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#Require SSL on checkout
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^onestepcheckout\/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am also vaguely cautious that the `/onestepcheckout/` does not contain secure resources and therefore an exception may need adding to images and style sheets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that while the paths in the RewriteRule are evaluated relative to the context of the .htaccess file, the REQUEST_URI variable relates back to the actual request and therefore contains the initial slash.

So you need

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/onestepcheckout\/?$
```

Alternatively, you could refer to the captured part from the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^onestepcheckout/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} onestepcheckout
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```